# Does the integral $\int_0^{\infty}e^{cx^2+dx}dx/(a+bx)$ have a closed form?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions

The integral is
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dm}{d\!}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-cx^2+dx}}{a+bx}\dm x.
$$
Here I assume that $a,b,c,d$ are chosen to make this integral convergent. Rewritting the rational function as a integral over exponential, I get
$$
I=\int_{x,y\ge 0}e^{-cx^2-bxy+dx-ay}\dm x\!\dm y.
$$
The exponential $\exp(-cx^2-byx)$ can be expressed as the generating function
$$
e^{-cx^2-byx}=\sum_n\frac{(\sqrt{c}x)^n}{n!}H_n\left(-by/2\right),
$$
where $H_n(x)$ is the Hermite polynomials. Substituting into integrand, I can integrate over $x$ and get
$$
I=\sum_n\frac{c^{n/2}}{n!(-d)^{n+1}}\Gamma(1+n)\int_0^{\infty}H_n(-by/2)e^{-ay}\ \dm y.
$$
This integral over $y$ is nothing but the Laplace-transform of Hermite polynomials. Seeding it to MMA then I end up with a pretty awful sum of series to $n$ like this
$$
I\sim\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{n!}\frac{c^{n/2}}{(-d)^{n+1}}\frac{2^{n-1}e^{-in\pi/2-a^2/b^2}\left(-2a/b\right)^{n+1}\Gamma(-n/2)\Gamma(1+n/2,-a^2/b^2)}{\Gamma(-n)}.
$$
Is it possible to complete this summation over $n$?

Comment: If you accept the error function as a "closed form", yes. Just feed it into Mathematica or similar.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt. I've already tried MMA while MMA gave nothing.

Comment: Ah - sorry. My earlier comment resulted from overly hurried, erroneous typing into Mathematica. Indeed, it doesn't yield a closed form. I should look before typing.

Comment: there is a "closed form" for $d=0$

Comment: If you accept the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), the [Shi function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html) and the [Chi function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html) as a "closed form" there is a "closed form" for $d = 0$ given by [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlYWX.png) according to Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: MSE is a right place for such type questions.

Comment: Possibly useful: this can be re-expressed as $\int_{x,y\geqslant0}\exp\left(c\cdot x^{2}-b\cdot x\cdot y+d\cdot x-a\cdot y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: @πr8 This is exactly the way I got my integral form in my question.

Comment: Okay. This reduction suggests to me that the integral can be interpreted as (a suitable limit of) the probability of a certain two-dimensional Gaussian random variable having both entries be positive. My guess is that this is as much of a 'closed form' that one can expect.

Comment: Is the answer for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ldots$ of relevance for you?

Comment: Also, are the parameters real or complex?

Comment: By standard operations (completing the square, changing variable, fraction decomposition) I think you can reduce the integral to integrals of the form 

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\lambda t}{1+\sqrt{t+\mu}} dt,$$
for positive $\lambda,\mu$, the Laplace transform of $\frac 1{1+\sqrt{t+\mu}} $

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but an alternate approach for another infinite summation.*

For sure, I assume that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive.

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dm}{d\!}
\frac{e^{-cx^2+dx}}{a+bx}=\frac{e^{-cx^2}}{a+bx}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n!} \frac{e^{-c x^2} x^n}{(a+b x)}\,d^n$$

As already said in comments (replacing $\text{Shi}$ and $\text{Chi}$ by more "trivial" functions)
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-cx^2}}{a+bx}\,\dm x=\frac 1{2b}\,e^{-\frac{a^2 c}{b^2}} \left(\pi \, \text{erfi}\left(\frac{a
   \sqrt{c}}{b}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{a^2
   c}{b^2}\right)\right)$$

$$J_n=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-cx^2}}{a+bx}x^n\,\dm x=\frac {i^n}{4b}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n\,\,e^{-\frac{a^2 c}{b^2}}\, A_n$$ where
$$A_n=n\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\, \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{a^2 c}{b^2}\right)+2\, i\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1-n}{2},-\frac{a^2 c}{b^2}\right)$$

Computing the partial sums for the case of $a=b=c=d=1$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0.886227 \\
 2 & 0.995680 \\
 3 & 1.033048 \\
 4 & 1.044539 \\
 5 & 1.047780 \\
 6 & 1.048629 \\
 7 & 1.048837 \\
 8 & 1.048886 \\
 9 & 1.048896 \\
 10 & 1.048899 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$